# How to make flash video stay in fullscreen on dual monitor setup?

Tags: flash, macos, google-chrome, fullscreen

Cant figure this out, got it to work in firefox a while ago but after upgrading to mac and chrome, I had no luck finding an solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be more of a Super User question - but at any rate, [this tool](http://jmaxxz.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=94%3adrizzlychrome&catid=16%3adownloads&Itemid=32) did the trick for me.

As with any hack, use it at your own risk.